# Android kitkat API 19, Intent.ACTION_VIEW not working

Tags: java, android, api, android-4.4-kitkat

I have used this line of code for opening URL in the default browser of the phone

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse("http://www.myurl.com")));
```

Now on Android KitKat, running my project on the emulator device with GoogleApi 19 the screen becomes black and "Browser stopped working" error appear...

What's wrong with this new version and my code?

This is the log

```
12-06 10:49:53.176: E/WindowManager(384): Starting window AppWindowToken{b468a060  token=Token{b4394958 ActivityRecord{b409c568 u0 com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity t15}}} timed out
12-06 10:50:43.776: E/NativeDaemonConnector.ResponseQueue(384): Timeout waiting for response
12-06 10:50:43.776: E/VoldConnector(384): timed-out waiting for response to 6 volume mkdirs /storage/sdcard/Android/data/com.android.browser/files/
12-06 10:50:43.806: D/AndroidRuntime(1891): Shutting down VM
12-06 10:50:43.816: W/dalvikvm(1891): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a6cb90)
12-06 10:50:43.846: E/AndroidRuntime(1891): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-06 10:50:43.846: E/AndroidRuntime(1891): Process: com.android.browser, PID: 1891
12-06 10:50:43.846: E/AndroidRuntime(1891): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.android.browser.provider.SnapshotProvider: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 10:50:43.846: E/AndroidRuntime(1891):     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4774)
12-06 10:50:43.846: E/AndroidRuntime(1891):     at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4366)
12-06 10:50:43.846: E/AndroidRuntime(1891):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4306)
12-06 10:50:43.846: E/AndroidRuntime(1891):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:135)
12-06 10:50:43.846: E/AndroidRuntime(1891):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1457)
12-06 10:50:43.846: E/AndroidRuntime(1891):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-06 10:50:43.846: E/AndroidRuntime(1891):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-06 10:50:43.846: E/AndroidRuntime(1891):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
12-06 10:50:43.846: E/AndroidRuntime(1891):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-06 10:50:43.846: E/AndroidRuntime(1891):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-06 10:50:43.846: E/AndroidRuntime(1891):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
12-06 10:50:43.846: E/AndroidRuntime(1891):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
12-06 10:50:43.846: E/AndroidRuntime(1891):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-06 10:50:43.846: E/AndroidRuntime(1891): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 10:50:43.846: E/AndroidRuntime(1891):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1467)
12-06 10:50:43.846: E/AndroidRuntime(1891):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1415)
12-06 10:50:43.846: E/AndroidRuntime(1891):     at android.os.storage.IMountService$Stub$Proxy.mkdirs(IMountService.java:750)
12-06 10:50:43.846: E/AndroidRuntime(1891):     at android.app.ContextImpl.ensureDirsExistOrFilter(ContextImpl.java:2160)
12-06 10:50:43.846: E/AndroidRuntime(1891):     at android.app.ContextImpl.getExternalFilesDirs(ContextImpl.java:856)
12-06 10:50:43.846: E/AndroidRuntime(1891):     at android.app.ContextImpl.getExternalFilesDir(ContextImpl.java:839)
12-06 10:50:43.846: E/AndroidRuntime(1891):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getExternalFilesDir(ContextWrapper.java:210)
12-06 10:50:43.846: E/AndroidRuntime(1891):     at com.android.browser.provider.SnapshotProvider.getOldDatabasePath(SnapshotProvider.java:116)
12-06 10:50:43.846: E/AndroidRuntime(1891):     at com.android.browser.provider.SnapshotProvider.migrateToDataFolder(SnapshotProvider.java:123)
12-06 10:50:43.846: E/AndroidRuntime(1891):     at com.android.browser.provider.SnapshotProvider.onCreate(SnapshotProvider.java:137)
12-06 10:50:43.846: E/AndroidRuntime(1891):     at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1589)
12-06 10:50:43.846: E/AndroidRuntime(1891):     at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1560)
12-06 10:50:43.846: E/AndroidRuntime(1891):     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4771)
12-06 10:50:43.846: E/AndroidRuntime(1891):     ... 12 more
12-06 10:50:43.856: W/ActivityManager(384):   Force finishing activity com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity
12-06 10:50:43.886: W/ActivityManager(384):   Force finishing activity com.irideprogetti.senigallia.it/.MainEventi
```

Comment: Please add the relevant section of your logcat.

Comment: possibly need setDataAndType.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me

```
 public static void openBrowser(final Context context, String url)
    {
        if (!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://"))
        {
            url = "http://" + url;
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Chose browser"));
    }
```

Comment: Your code works well, but the emulators says "No apps can perform this action"
How is possible the default installed browser isn't recognized as default browser?

Comment: try on real device , because emulator doesn't have additional browsers

Comment: ok, so the problem is the emulator and not the code, my code doesn't give the browser choice, so it becomes black, while your code helped me to figure where the problem is. 
I'll try to download the API 19 tools again from SDK Manager and see if things change. Thank you very much for help :)

Comment: I'v found the solution which worked for me

Added a random number to SD image size in AVD setting, check the image

http://i.stack.imgur.com/6Q25v.png